# Why did Dr. Manhattan choose the hydrogen atom for the symbol on his forehead?

Tags: character, watchmen

In the alternate versions of [Watchmen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchmen_%28film%29), when  Dr. Manhattan's is forced to choose a symbol, he made one on his forehead representing a hydrogen atom.

Why did he choose this symbol? How does it relate to him?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't read *Watchmen*; you really should go read it. =)

Comment: @jamesdlin thinking to go for it someday but lack of time for reading.

Comment: I think its because its the first element and most basic so by theorectical extension makes up everything else. like how all brick structures *could* be icon'd with a brick.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> He [Dr. Manhattan / Jon] is also provided with a costume which he grudgingly accepts, though he refuses to accept the icon design which is provided for him (this being a stylized orbital model of the atom). Instead, Jon chooses as his emblem a representation of a hydrogen atom, whose simplicity he declares to be something that kindles his respect; accordingly, he painlessly burns the mark into his forehead. This preference for material mechanisms marks the beginning of Jon's declining humanity, which is progressively mirrored by his gradual shedding of the uniform - by the end of the 1970s, he refuses to wear anything at all except for mandatory public appearances.

<sup>Source: ["Jonathan Osterman (Watchmen)", DC Comics Database](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Jonathan_Osterman_%28Watchmen%29)</sup>
[image]
<sup>Image source: Watchmen, Chapter IV</sup>

---

#### Out-of-universe

Out-of-universe, this scene is an influence of or carried over from Charlton Comics' [Captain Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Atom).

> *Watchmen* originated from a story proposal Moore submitted to DC featuring superhero characters that the company had acquired from Charlton Comics. As Moore's proposed story would have left many of the characters unusable for future stories, managing editor Dick Giordano convinced Moore to create original characters instead.

<sup>Source: ["Watchmen", Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchmen)</sup>

> Alan Moore: ...So, we started to reshape the concept—using the Charlton characters as the jumping-off point, because those were the ones we submitted to Dick—and that's what the plot involved. We started to mutate the characters, and I began to realize the changes allowed me so much more freedom. The only idea of Captain Atom as a nuclear super-hero—that had the shadow of the atom bomb hung around him—had been part of the original proposal, but with Dr. Manhattan, by making him kind of a quantum super-hero, it took it into a whole new dimension, it wasn't just the shadow of the nuclear threat around him. The things that we could do with Dr. Manhattan's consciousness and the way he saw time wouldn't have been appropriate for Captain Atom...

> Comic Book Artist: Just to map this out: The prototype for Rorshach was The Question, right?
>
> Alan Moore: The Question was Rorschach, yep. Dr. Manhattan and Captain Atom were obviously equivalent.

<sup>Source: ["Alan Moore discusses the Charlton-Watchmen Connection", Comic Book Artist #9](https://www.twomorrows.com/comicbookartist/articles/09moore.html)
[image]</sup>

<sup>Image source: [Who's Who: The Definitive Directory of the DC Universe Vol. 1 #4](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Who%27s_Who:_The_Definitive_Directory_of_the_DC_Universe_Vol_1_4) as uploaded in [DC Comics Database](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Allen_Adam_%28Earth-Four%29)</sup>

The Charlton Comics universe is currently known as 'Earth-4' in DC Comics. For comparison, here's the [current Earth-4 Captain Atom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXFrN.jpg) (whose design is influenced by the Watchmen's Dr. Manhattan).
Image source: [The Multiversity - Guidebook: Maps and Legends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Multiversity#Guidebook:_Maps_and_Legends)

Comment: I think the image from the very recent Multiversity is slightly less relevant than an image of the pre-Crisis Captain Atom and/or additional Charlton characters.

Comment: @JoshDM I added an image of the pre-Crisis Captain Atom.

Comment: The older Captain Atom actually negates your argument... Dr. Manhattan specifically refuses to wear a hat that has that symbol on it.

Comment: @Catija I'm not arguing that the symbol was directly copied from Charlton Comics' Captain Atom, but just mentioning that out-of-universe, it is most likely influenced by or carried over from it. In-universe, my explanation is the same as the excerpt I quoted from the DC Comics Database, "*...a hydrogen atom, whose simplicity he declares to be something that kindles his respect.*"

Comment: I guess I just don't see the need for the older image as it doesn't help your argument at all. The newer image is much more similar to the Dr. Manhattan character.

Comment: @Catija - The image of the original Captain Atom shows where the "traditional" icon from the helmet was sourced.

Comment: @JoshDM Does it? The answer doesn't say that. It's just a bunch of images very little actual explanation.

Comment: @JoshDM Have you actually read all of my comments? I know that... and I think that including that info goes counter to the argument because Dr. Manhattan **refuses** to wear that symbol.  But the answer should be more explicit about what it's saying.  If it's trying to draw that connection... you aren't the answerer, so you can't **actually** know that that was his intent when adding the image because he doesn't **say** that anywhere in the answer.

Comment: @Catija - the reason NOT to use an image from Multiversity is because those versions of the Charlton characters do not represent the Charlton characters that inspired the Watchmen characters (and the Dr. Manhattan character in question); rather they are re-interpretations of the Charlton characters using influences from Watchmen.  "Captain Allan Adam of Earth 4" is an amalgam of Captain Atom and Dr. Manhattan, created over 20 years after-the-fact, and misrepresents the Captain Atom from which Dr. Manhattan is derived.

Comment: @JoshDM Maybe I'm missing something... I'm not an expert on Watchmen by any means... but, as someone with **eyes** I'd say that the similarities between the Dr. Manhattan and the Mulitversity image is obvious... but practically non-existant between Dr. Manhattan and Captain Atom.

Answer (score 6):

From the comic, Dr. Manhattan chooses the Hydrogen atom because he wants a symbol he can "respect":

[image: Dr. Manhattan chooses his symbol]

The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Manhattan) article for his character simply states:

> Instead, Jon chooses as his emblem a representation of a hydrogen atom, whose simplicity he declares to be something that kindles his respect; accordingly, he painlessly burns the mark into his forehead.

I couldn't find much other sure info but, there's a lot of conjecture out there, including [relating his name to the fusion bomb](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090306232235AAk1Syu), which is a hydrogen bomb and the creation part of the [Manhattan Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermonuclear_weapon#American_developments); and inferring that, as hydrogen is the simplest element, and most abundant, it was appropriate for him.

Answer (score -4):

Great answers from my colleagues, but I think they missed the obvious answer: [The Manhattan Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_Project).

The first sentence of the Wiki states:

> The Manhattan Project was a research and development project that
>   produced the first atomic bombs during World War II.

There has been at least one movie about the subject, and I'm sure plenty of books as well.

Comment: And the connection to the hydrogen atom would then be...?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_weapon - the first atomic bomb was created with hydrogen

Comment: @phalacee No, the first atomic bombs (1945) were based on the fission of the large atoms uranium or plutonium. Fusion bombs (using hydrogen) were much more complicated and came later (1952).